# Unions and intersections of RawQuerySets and QuerySets in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Is it possible to somehow turn a `RawQuerySet` into a `QuerySet` or otherwise emulate the `__and__` and `__or__` methods of `QuerySet` onto `RawQuerySet` so that I can get the union and intersection of a `RawQuerySet` and a `QuerySet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://gist.github.com/carymrobbins/8477219) ended up helping me out a great deal.

Full snippet:

```
from django.db import connection, models

class MyManager(Manager):
    def raw_as_qs(self, raw_query, params=()):
        """Execute a raw query and return a QuerySet.  The first column in the
        result set must be the id field for the model.
        :type raw_query: str | unicode
        :type params: tuple[T] | dict[str | unicode, T]
        :rtype: django.db.models.query.QuerySet
        """
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.execute(raw_query, params)
            return self.filter(id__in=(x[0] for x in cursor))
        finally:
            cursor.close()


class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = MyManager()
```

Comment: NameError: name 'Manager' is not defined. in Class MyManager(Manager) do you mean models.Manager? I tried this script but it returns an empty list